# Make HLint ignore parse error due to multi-way if?

Tags: haskell, hlint

I'm using the `MultiWayIf` language extension. While I love HLint (I'm using version v1.8.61), unfortunately it appears that HLint is not aware of this extension, and it reports multi-way ifs as parse errors:
`Warning: Parse error: |`

The HLint Manual (http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/darcs/hlint/hlint.htm) describes how you can use pragmas to indicate suggestions to ignore; however, this doesn't seem to work for warnings due to parse errors.

Is there any way to tell HLint to ignore the parse error warnings?
Thank you!

Comment: What version of haskell-src-exts is it linked with? The changelog for HSE says it added support for MultiWayIf in 1.15.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can run:

```
hlint "--ignore=Parse error" MyFile.hs
```

There is a test that this invocation works in the [HLint test suite](https://github.com/ndmitchell/hlint/blob/master/tests/parse-error.test).

Note that as soon as there is a parse error you won't get any other hints from the file, since HLint can't operate on a file until it is parsed.

However, if you upgrade to haskell-src-exts-1.15 or higher then reinstall HLint it should parse multi-way-if fine. If not, please [report a bug](https://github.com/haskell-suite/haskell-src-exts/issues).

Comment: Upgrading `haskell-src-exts` and reinstalling HLint (`cabal install --reinstall hlint`) worked for me. Thank you very much!